# Equivalent regular expression

Tags: regex, codeigniter, expression

I have this Regular Expression:

```
/^(?:'[A-z](([\._\-][A-z0-9])|[A-z0-9])*[a-z0-9_]*')$/
```

and I'm trying to build an equivalent one, still no success.

For more information, it's a regex for a username. This are the rules:

- Should start with a letter
- Can have . - or _ in the middle of the username (like john__, or john.m, or kate-7)
- Can't end with . or -, but it can end with several _ (like matt__)
- Can end with numbers (like chloe77)

**EDIT:**

I'm using Codeigniter regex_match and it has a bug, doesn't accept pipes. So the equivalent regular expression should not have the pipe.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What language are you using? What's wrong with the one you have?

Comment: Why do you use non-capturing group for the whole fragment? You can omit `(?:` and `)`.

Comment: @remus the regular expression I posted I'm using it in jQuery for form validation. Now i'm using codeigniter and can't have the pipe in the middle because it breaks!

Comment: The one in my answer should work in both, provided you're properly delimiting the expression in php.

Comment: @remus I'm sorry i forgot to tell that it can't have pipes! because of Codeigniter's regex_match bug.

Comment: @MaximKhan-Magomedov because that is how additional-methods.js matches the regular expression. It has a function that checks if pattern is ok

Comment: @Limon you can't match what you want without the pipe - see http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/220094/#1014320. You will probably need to create a custom validation rule.

Comment: Also this: https://github.com/henriqueoliveira/CodeIgniter/commit/d33ee5dce191264c211f27199826d54731fed3c5 Looks like it's been fixed in this fork two years ago. Are you using the latest version of CI?

Comment: @remus yes I'm using the last version! thanks for the info. I rather not use the pipe

Comment: @Limon then you're going to have to reduce your criteria or check it twice somehow (if match the first option, ok, if not, try second option). See my updated answer -has an if/else statement.

Comment: Important tip: **DO NOT USE `[A-z]` IN A REGEX.**  It matches all uppercase and lowercase ASCII letters as you expect, but it also matches several punctuation characters whose code points happen to lie between `Z` and `a`.  Either use `[a-z]` and apply the case-insensitive modifier (preferable), or use `[A-Za-z]`.

Comment: @AlanMoore thank you, I'm changing it right away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(?:[a-zA-Z](?:[a-zA-Z0-9._-]*[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)?)$
```

http://regex101.com/r/jX2wY5

Comment: The error says: Message: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^' found

Comment: thank you, it worked when I added two slashes. So the way to go is: /^(?:[a-zA-Z](?:[a-zA-Z0-9._-]*[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)?)$/

Comment: The delimiters are required for a php regular expression ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a PCRE (or mostly) compliant language, try this:

```
/^([A-Z][\w.-]*[A-Z_\d]|[A-Z])$/i
```

http://regex101.com/r/hS7mB9

In javascript:

```
var str = "john.m"; //example
console.log((/^([A-Z][\w.-]*[A-Z_\d]|[A-Z])$/i).test(str));
```

In php:

```
$str = "john.m"; //example
if (!preg_match("/^([A-Z][\w.-]*[A-Z_\d]|[A-Z])$/i", $str);
```

Without the `|`:

```
$str = ".John.m";
if (preg_match("/^[A-Z]$/i", $str))
{
    //check if it's one letter
}
else if (preg_match("/^[A-Z][\w.-]*[A-Z_\d]/i", $str))
{
    //if not, check if it fits the other format
}
else
{
    //we can assume that it's now failed the test
}
```

Comment: Wan't match short inputs, e.g. `a`, `ab`, `a0`, etc.

Comment: @RyanWheale OHHHH well why didn't you say so :P

Comment: @remus see please my comment on the top and thanks for the effort

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I was just saying to @MarcinJuraszek what he posted was ok..just needed two slashes